# error: "Please use POST request" with Form and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, function

I made a small form and I want it to post information back to the user when the inputs are left blank.

For some reason it says please use post request, so I added it and now it gives me a different error message.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/pwtnY/

```
<div id="main">
<form name="myForm" method="post">
    <label><span>First Name:</span><input type="text" class="firstname" name="fname"></label><br/>
    <label><span>Last Name:</span><input type="text" class="lastname"></label><br>
    <label><span>E-Mail:</span><input type="text" class="email"></label><br/>
    <label><span>Phone:</span><input type="text" class="phone"></label><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="answer"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
       $firstname = $('.firstname').val();
       $lastname = $('.lastname').val();
       $email = $('.email').val();
       $phone = $('.phone').val();

       if($firstname === "" && $lastname==="" && $email ==="" && $phone === ""){
           $("#answer").html("Please fill out all fields.");
       }

   });
});
```

Anyone know what the problem could be and how I could go about solving it?

Comment: did you try to find the actual error? More information is available with DEBUG=True.

Comment: I don't know, how would I add that. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: in your settings.py file.

Comment: I'm just doing this all on jsfiddle for practice. Link at top.

Answer (score 3):

When you click submit, the form is actually posting to your django backend. If you want to do frontend validation before posting to your server, prevent the submit button from actually posting.

```
$('input:submit').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $firstname = $('.firstname').val();
```

Comment: Still not working in the jsfiddle. I left a link at the top. Is something supposed to replace event?

Comment: You needed to add jquery to the fiddle. I added the event.preventDefault() and jquery here - http://jsfiddle.net/andyzinsser/pwtnY/20/

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you haven't included jquery library. If you don't want to submit anything to the server, replace submit button with simple button `<input type="button" value="submit">`. There is updated your example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwtnY/18/)

P.S. You probably want to use OR instead of AND in your validation to validate if any of the fields is empty